# Oracle SQL Developer Query on recommended password setup

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Setting up a random password for user using

```
select 
dbms_random.string('L',2) || dbms_random.string('X',6) || '1!' as deflvrpwd,
'${access_request_cri_acc_cas9}' as ACNTDN
from dual
```

New requirement

```
New Hire Details:
Name :John Doe 
Region: America
WDID : 876214
```

**WDID Reverse and split
Region in the middle with the letter A replaced with @ symbol**

Should read if we follow your formula.

```
= 412@meric@s678
```

Please suggest attribute are same as mentioned.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     -- sample data
  3     test (name, region, wdid)
  4     AS
  5        (SELECT 'John Doe', 'America', '876214' FROM DUAL),
  6     temp
  7     AS
  8        -- reverse WDID; don't use undocumented REVERSE function
  9        -- replace "A" (or "a") with "@" in REGION
 10        (  SELECT name,
 11                  REPLACE (REPLACE (region, 'A', '@'), 'a', '@') new_region,
 12                  LISTAGG (letter, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl DESC) new_wdid
 13             FROM (    SELECT SUBSTR (wdid, LEVEL, 1) letter,
 14                              LEVEL lvl,
 15                              name,
 16                              region
 17                         FROM test
 18                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (wdid))
 19         GROUP BY name, region)
 20  -- finally
 21  SELECT SUBSTR (new_wdid, 1, 3) || new_region || SUBSTR (new_wdid, 4) AS result
 22    FROM temp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
412@meric@678

SQL>
```

I don't know where `s` in your result comes from (this: 412@meric@**s**678).

Answer (score 0):

There's a small cost in context switching between SQL and PL/SQL, but this doesn't sound like a high-volume or performance-critical thing, so you might find it cleaner to put the logic in a function:

```
create or replace function get_password (p_wdid varchar2, p_region varchar2)
return varchar2 as
  l_split pls_integer;
  l_password varchar2(30);
begin
  -- split WDID halfway, but allow for odd lengths
  l_split := floor(length(p_wdid)/2);

  -- iterate over the WDID in reverse
  for i in reverse 1..length(p_wdid) LOOP
    -- when we reach the split point, append the modified region
    if i = l_split then
      l_password := l_password || translate(p_region, 'Aax', '@@x');
    end if;
    -- append each WDID character, in reverse order
    l_password := l_password || substr(p_wdid, i, 1);
  end loop;

  return l_password;
end get_password;
/
```

The WDID is reversed in a loop, and the modified region is included at the midway point, based on the length of the WDID value.

You can then do:

```
select get_password('876214', 'America') from dual;

GET_PASSWORD('876214','AMERICA')
--------------------------------
412@meric@678
```

This also doesn't have the unexplained 's' from the example in your question.

If you can't create a function but are on a recent version of Oracle then you can define an ad hoc function in a CTE:

```
with
  function invert (p_input varchar2) return varchar2 as
    l_output varchar2(30);
  begin
    for i in reverse 1..length(p_input) LOOP
      l_output := l_output || substr(p_input, i, 1);
    end loop;
    return l_output;
  end invert;
t (wdid, region) as (
  select invert('876214'), translate('America', 'Aax', '@@x')
  from dual
)
select substr(wdid, 1, floor(length(wdid)/2))
  || region
  || substr(wdid, floor(length(wdid)/2) + 1)
from t;
```

which gets the same result. (I've called the function `invert` to avoid confusion with the undocumented `reverse` function.)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7cc511611cae17fa113d6b3bdaae4085) showing both.